# How do I define a TypeScript *type* that will reduce a record of functions to an overloaded function signature?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to define a type for the following TypeScript function:

```js
function Trait<
    TS extends { [key: string]: (...args: any) => any}
>(ts: TS): TraitType<TS> { 
    // details removed
}

const printLang = Trait({
    Alt: ({left, right}) => `${left}|${right}`,
    Char: ({value}) => `${value}`,
    Cat: ({first, second}) => `${first},${second}`
})

// overload signature or a union type expected
printLang({left: 'foo', right: 'bar'})
printLang({value: 'baz'})
printLang({first: 'qux', second: 'quux'})
printLang({error: '?'}) // error expected
```

The problem though is that I can get close, but at some point the type checker generalizes excessively.

```js
type TraitType<TS extends { [key: string]: (...args: any) => any}> = 
    TS[keyof TS]
```

yields only the first definition:

[image]

The following gets closer and provides a union for the arguments which is desired, but I need to get the parameters of those unioned functions:

```js
type TraitType<TS extends { [key: string]: (...args: any) => any}> = 
    (self: TS[keyof TS]) => ReturnType<TS[keyof TS]>
```

[image]

So when I attempt to do so, TypeScript no longer returns a union:

```js
type TraitType<TS extends { [key: string]: (...args: any) => any}> = 
    (...args: Parameters<TS[keyof TS]>) => ReturnType<TS[keyof TS]>
```

[image]

Any assistance or feedback provided would be appreciated.

[Scratchpad here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwJbBuCAeGBlKEAewEAdgCYDOUA3lANoDWEIAXFOcHEsQOYC6rACgB0IhHG7lWCYiACUUALwA%20KNJABfFQqgAoKPqjDR4yVAAKYhAFsIROOSzYGTAPYAzWNl5L5yqACVbAFc4YjRIR2cQd09vPQMAegSBcggAGzdWHCiYnF5fFUDgELD0SMZojzyleP0k7Ircr1qoJIEXMGBWKloAaSguKEaqr1YLRBs7B2ze73UCgODQ8MwG1xG4nSSoUEhYRBQVjH88QhIKRYBjFzhSDHZOHgAaQxEhMQkpGVp8xRU1JRaV7GT7ULYJAz6PoDYhDdYBfjmSyTCD2Y59OLbdQ5Dz%20X5%20KjgyF0fqDYYI1hFEpHfwYmpYnEIgDcOh0biCxEuwCQLlh8GQwAwLRwpyIZEoNCirAeXD4gjeH1MagWanUOiUAmAphwsiyB1QZRwKhoLW2pFsyDSlDgECsLgAbhBSDo1TprsR2FAwI9gAAZaTcRT7AUCQmQgCCaS6hioaQgbmAL043AAFsB5n8oAADAAksfj6YAPnnk2n1Fmni0AMIpsSCKj2hBpIIQDN%20XMNpst8uVyFVhDR0NuJD2RNsCDu0htlQd4ej9RPPOpSfll2yVk6b1cP0BgTr1lb4g7nihuMJ1gAcjcLhcF6TSFT0YvACMxBf5puff6T53mxBL6%20ABe77roex7cEOI7sJeACOQT4He46TrBQTwSBn7bt%20EFUKicA3JeAD8IGtBCuE3KckBck6G5AA)

Comment: Your main problem here is not with the typings for `Trait` but with your expectation of contextual typing of the callbacks you pass into it.  If you write `({left, right}) => ...` you are very likely going to get an implicit `{left, right}: any` which is not useful to you.  If you annotate your callback parameters properly, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mL5AeW), everything works, right?

Comment: So the issue is primarily one of contextual typing of destructured callback parameters and the answer to the question as asked is "annotate your callback parameters". I can write that up if you want.  But if that's not sufficient and you want something else, please [edit] the question to specify what that is.

Comment: Although your typings *are* a little off, in that they mix all the methods together so that every input gives a union of outputs, so you could fix that perhaps [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w1ALOw).  Is *that* what you're after?  Let me know how to proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz your second example seems most appropriate. My hope was that without the explicit typings I could at least get the structural types. After seeing you example, I don't think it's unreasonable to expect a client to annotate what is provided to the function.

Comment: @jcalz In your second example you also use the following: `[K in keyof T]-?` I am unfamiliar with the `-` suffix in this context. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I'll write up an answer with sources when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're running into is that TypeScript apparently has no capacity to simultaneously infer a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument and also [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) type related [destructured parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).  For example:

```
function nope<K extends string>(cb: (arg: Record<K, string>) => void) { }

nope(({ left, right }) => { left.toUpperCase(); right.toLowerCase() });
// function nope<string>(cb: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void): void
```

Here, the compiler is unable to infer `K` at all; it just falls back to its  [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), `string`, and thus the argument is of type `Record<string, string>`.  That means `left` and `right` in the body of the callback are both inferred as type `string`, but that's not what you need here.  You want `K` to be inferred as `"left" | "right"` and it just isn't.

If you want generic inference, you'll need to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the callback parameter, but unfortunately doing this is quite redundant:

```
nope(({ left, right }: { left: string, right: string }) => { });
// function nope<"left" | "right">(cb: 
//   (arg: Record<"left" | "right", string>) => void): void
```

That works; now `K` is inferred as `"left" | "right"`.  But it would be nice if you didn't have to write `{ left, right }: { left: string, right: string}`.  Currently though there's nothing nicer; see [ms/TS#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) for a feature request to support something like (maybe) `({left::string, right::string})=>...`.

---

So in what follows we have to annotate the callbacks.  Then I'd be inclined to give `Trait` the following call signature:

```
declare function Trait<
    T extends { [K in keyof T]: (arg: any) => any }
>(ts: T): { [K in keyof T]-?: (x: T[K]) => void }[keyof T] extends
    (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
```

What I'm doing here is converting the input type `T` to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all its members.  If `T` were `{a: A, b: B, c: C}`, then the return type would be `A & B & C`.  The reason we want an intersection is because TypeScript treats an intersection of function types the same as it treats [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

---

This intersection-of-methods is accomplished by a similar technique as in [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218).  First I make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where I put every property of `T` in *contravariant* position by mapping it to a function parameter.  This mapping is [modified](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) with `-?` to make any optional properties required, so that `undefined` doesn't show up and mess us up in the end.  So `{a: A, b: B, c: C}` would become `{a: (x: A)=>void, b:(x: B)=>void, c:(x:C)=>void}`.

Then, into this mapped type, I immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof T`, thereby getting the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of these functions: `(x: A)=>void) | ((x: B)=>void) | ((x: C)=>void)`.

Then I use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to match that union-of-functions to a single function of an inferred parameter type.  And because this is a union of things in contravariant position, the inferred parameter is the intersection of the individual candidates, as described [in the release notes for conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types): `A & B & C`.

---

So that's *how* it works... so let's see it actually working, remembering to annotate our callback parameters:

```
const printLang = Trait({
    Alt: ({ left, right }: { left: string, right: string }) => `${left}|${right}`,
    Len: ({ value }: { value: string }) => value.length,
    Arr: ({ first, second }: { first: string, second: string }) => [first, second]
})

/* const printLang: (({ left, right }: {
    left: string;
    right: string;
}) => string) & (({ value }: {
    value: string;
}) => number) & (({ first, second }: {
    first: string;
    second: string;
}) => string[]) */
```

As you can see, `printLang()` is now an intersection of three function types. And so it behaves as an overloaded function with three call signatures, as desired:

```
const str = printLang({ left: 'foo', right: 'bar' });
str.toUpperCase()
const num = printLang({ value: 'baz' });
num.toFixed()
const tup = printLang({ first: 'qux', second: 'quux' });
tup.map(x => x.toUpperCase())

printLang({ error: '?' }) // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOAHApgHgNKPQDynTABMBnRMqAJxjAHMA+ACggCMAuRZgQ2vq4AldBDjUSOADSUadJgEpEAXkaIAbnBglFAb0QBfAFAoMzZnoA26YFGm16ACygHFKxJetQAdFDgBVVAxqAGEeMnRmeQBuRHsnHzgAGTgAd3QQsIjFfWjDAHo8xFBIWARkNCwqWgYWdi5efiERMQkquWk2mtdVDS15Ll6SYwqzDxs7GEdnfS4xqC5O+gmphdkGF2VVPRyo-MLi6HgkEywAIisbU8QAH0RTuKhT2s5uPgFEYVFxTHPPK9v7pMnKcOmsFJt1JptAMoYY4SQRBY+OgiuBDmUACrUHgwKCYQyIQmIDF4QjEcjuRAAbVwdEQAGt0ABPODAYkAXXqby4PDATO6iF5TIMhhYUDIXAx-UpNMQdMZLLZGPZAFoAPz1fCSmnsgWDAxUhWsjmkoikMgEonMLVysDAdKIACSeqhiDVTsQXDA6DU6V2hlEYCoiFQ1SgiV59GUxOxuPMlsJAEELPNuHNlk4DLNEBdU4sM3mwRs3AADAAkOlz+muFYe+hLkgTiESxHqejUPAsIBRM0pHa76FW1SjOQh-e7XisDCgDkbRMQieo1DbRRg1CoHWapCzlOAa6oQ-alC3JEP61Hbipe-XtmPgZI7MMOXyACpEIHg6G6OHI-VzDnPALHcdCbXMz3oXZ5wecDdgvVRFkUAAybh-3HHtZibNCYKfAUwBAABbNh0iQlC9GvDc7wQEhgKbcjC2HSCiXCe9sLgmRhypXVEBfPI4Q-ZwqmjL8wB-Bh-zAxAAHJgDgOBJILLhJLYPhJJcXYqgSAIglCcJIgDBBgzw-ChLDCMxPbTtu0U5SAC9VJ2YwCISAAxGB8HQEg9P4xAoBAVATO-Mz6H-OjFIARxAfB5Mo0hwpASL7NyXzUC8fCeFQa0IXwTTAnSHSsnkOFhNE4K9HSagxEUtVEsQAo8CXMREDhQwgA)